# Change complex value in string by javascript

Tags: javascript

I am converting an object to a XML string that contains array as well, so I get some results like:

```
<some field>
   <0><other>text</other></0>
   <1><other>tetx</other></1>
```

How can I get easily get rid of those numbers? <0> etc

I am trying with an ugly solution... some replacements work, like the following, but can't figure out how to insert /g to make it global

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++) {       
    xmlAsStr = xmlAsStr.replace('<'+i+'>', ''); 
    xmlAsStr = xmlAsStr.replace('</'+i+'>', "");                        
    xmlAsStr = xmlAsStr.replace('<'+i+'/>', "");                        
}
```

RegExp not working at all!! Tried also inside same for loop

```
var find = '</'+i+'>';
var regex = new RegExp(find, "g");
xmlAsStr = xmlAsStr.replace(find, "");
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is generating the numbers to start? Can you stop that from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\d` matches digits, so this would work to remove all the opening tags with digits

```
myxmlstring.replace(/<\d>/g, '');
```

Keep in mind that slashes need to be escaped in regexes, so to match the closing version.

```
myxmlstring.replace(/<\/\d>/, '');
```

Finally, a use a question mark quantifier to match the closing slash zero or one time, catching both cases in a single regexp.

```
myxmlstring.replace(<\/?\d>, '');
```

To match more than one digit (e.g 10 and upwards) add a quantifier to the \d as-well. In this case + as it means one or unlimited times.

```
myxmlstring.replace(/<\/?\d+>/, '');
```

Comment: would fail with 10+ if it would go that high. `replace(/<\/?\d+>/g,"")` would probably be better

Comment: Thanks, (/<\/?\d+>/g,"") did the trick! Out of curiosity could I add a rule for <3/> as well?

Comment: Just move the slash matcher!
Play round with it on a site like https://regex101.com which has the "verbal" version of what is going on up on the right hand corner.

Answer (score -1):

```
var regexStr = "/<\d*>/g";
xmlAsStr.replace(regexStr,"");
```

the replace function can solve regex expression,you don't need to create RegExp object,and `/d` mean number object such as 0-9 and the `*` mean it can repeat many times.